# Shorten Android Web Link

Tags: android

I have searched in the answers and have tried some suggestions which haven´t worked.

I have an android app, which has a url which the user can click and it takes him to my website.

In the English language XML Strings file the url appears like this:

```
<string name="website_url" translatable="false">http://travelwebsite2.com/es/home/312-travel-special-offers.html</string>
```

How can I show the user the url "www.travelwebsite2.com", but when he clicks it, it takes him to the full url mentioned before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
<a href='http://travelwebsite2.com/es/home/312-travel-special-offers.html'>www.travelwebsite2.com</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The finally string would appear like this? <string name="website_url" translatable="false"><a href='http://travelwebsite2.com/es/home/312-travel-special-offers.html'>www.travelwebsite2.com</string>